# Angular scope not updating after service call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-services, angular-controller

I have a controller and service.

The service performs a `http.get` and return true if successful and false if error.

However, in the controller, it receives `true` or false correctly, but the html of the binding always displays as true??

Controller:

```
app.controller('MyController', function($scope, MyService) {

    MyService.getData(function(isLoggedIn, userData) {

        var loggedIn = isLoggedIn;    
        $scope.isLoggedIn = loggedIn;
        $scope.myUser = userData;
        //$scope.$evalAsync();
        //$scope.$apply();            
    });    
});

app.factory('MyService', function($http, $q) {
    return {

        getData: function(isLoggedIn, userModel) {
            $http.get('../assets/data/data.json')
                .success(function(data) {
                    userModel(data);
                    isLoggedIn(true);
                })
                .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    // If 400 or 404 are returned, the user is not signed in.
                    if (status == 400 || status == 401 || status == 404) {
                        isLoggedIn(false);
                    }                    
                });
        }
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
{{isLoggedIn}}
```

In the above, `{{isLoggedIn}}` is always true. Even when i modify the http call to:

```
$http.get('../blah/blah/blah.json')
```

In the effort to force a .error/fail.

I've tried $scope.$apply() and i keep getting the error of a digest cycle in process. help!!!

Comment: Your using `isLoggedIn` and `userModel` in the service like they're methods... what are you passing into the service?

Comment: @tymeJV - im passing nothing to the service..

Comment: `getData` is defined with two parameters, you are passing one argument (the anonymous function). And `userModel` in the `$http.get` callback is going to be `undefined` as you didnt pass a second argument so `userModel(data);` should be throwing an error, did you check your console?

Comment: @PatrickEvans - correct, userModel is throwing an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're a bit confused as to how the callbacks are working. Your `isLoggedIn` param in the service is the *callback function* that you're passing in. Your code corrected:

```
app.controller('MyController', function($scope, MyService) {

    /*
    The function(response) { is your callback function being passed to the service
    */
    MyService.getData(function(response) {
        var loggedIn = response.isLoggedIn;    
        $scope.isLoggedIn = loggedIn;
        $scope.myUser = response.userModel;           
    });    
});

app.factory('MyService', function($http, $q) {
    return {
        getData: function(callback) {
            $http.get('../assets/data/data.json')
                .success(function(data) {
                    //Execute your callback function and pass what data you need
                    callback({userModel: data, isLoggedIn: true});
                })
                .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    // If 400 or 404 are returned, the user is not signed in.
                    if (status == 400 || status == 401 || status == 404) {
                        callback({isLoggedIn: false});
                    }                    
                });
        }
    }
});
```

You should be using promises... here's an even more refactored version:

```
app.controller('MyController', function($scope, MyService) {
    MyService.getData().then(function(response) {
        var loggedIn = response.isLoggedIn;    
        $scope.isLoggedIn = loggedIn;
        $scope.myUser = response.userModel;           
    });    
});

app.factory('MyService', function($http, $q) {
    return {
        getData: function() {
            return $http.get('../assets/data/data.json')
                .then(function(response) {
                    return {
                        userModel: response.data, 
                        isLoggedIn: true
                    };
                }, function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    // If 400 or 404 are returned, the user is not signed in.
                    if (status == 400 || status == 401 || status == 404) {
                        return {isLoggedIn: false};
                    }                    
                });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks that makes sense, there are 3 levels of return in the refactored version, are all necessary? Just trying to understand it a bit more..

Comment: Yeah... so the first `return` is just your object with all your calls as functions. The second `return` returns the entire `$http` promise, and the 3rd returns the data from the `$http` call to be accessible via `.then` @OamPsy

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, {{isLoggedIn}} is still displaying as true in the html when a console.log of it is false

Comment: Where are you logging it? Is the service returning `false`?